# How to get specific version of SDK from GetFrameworkSdkPath in MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

I would like to be able to pull out the mage.exe and add it to my deployment package during the build process.  I need to be able to pull the specific version of mage.exe tool depending on the framework version of the current target.  So, for example, when building a .NET 4.0 project, I want to package the mage.exe from (Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools) and not (Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools).

I'm using GetFrameworkSdkPath Task in the build process but it doesn't seem to pull back the correct SDK version path..

Here's my current approach:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'=='v2.0'">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SDKVersionPath>FrameworkSdkVersion20Path</SDKVersionPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'=='v3.5'">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SDKVersionPath>FrameworkSdkVersion35Path</SDKVersionPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
<When Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)'=='v4.0'">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SDKVersionPath>FrameworkSdkVersion40Path</SDKVersionPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
</Choose>

<Target Name="GetSDKVersionPath">
 <PropertyGroup>
   <SDKVersionPath Condition="$(SDKVersionPath)==''">Path</SDKVersionPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Message Text="SDK VERSION PATH: $(SDKVersionPath)"/>
 <GetFrameworkSdkPath>
   <Output
       TaskParameter="$(SDKVersionPath)"
       PropertyName="SdkPath" />
 </GetFrameworkSdkPath>
</Target>
```

With this approach, when the framework version is 'v4.0', it gives me the path to SDK v10.0A instead of v8.0A as expected.

Any ideas on how to get the path to the correct version of mage.exe in SDK?